# How to use let values from different js file to app.js in React

Tags: reactjs, file, include

I am using react-localization and defined code for language variable
in App.js

```
import LocalizedStrings from "react-localization";

let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  en: {
    how: "how are you"
  },
  it: {
    how: "Come vuoi il tuo uovo oggi?"
  }
});

export strings;
```

We can use that in App.js as {strings.how} but my question is that the when the language value is increase in large extent can we move this in different lang.js file and call it in app.js.

How I import and use the "let strings" from a different file?

Comment: You can export it with `export { strings };` and then import it in another file with `import { strings } from './path/to/file.js'`

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a named export with the following:

```
export { strings };
```

Then you can import it in another file like this:

```
import { strings } from './path/to/file.js'
```